# Appcelerator: Trying to add a module to my project

Tags: ios, module, appcelerator

Im trying to add a module to my project but once its added and i add my code to tiapp.xml, it will not build for ios. I get SystemExit: 65

In android it will build but crashes when it comes to the part that uses the module.

Titanium skd - 1.8.2 
Xcode - 4.3 
Running on Mac osx lion.

Yes, ive tried a clean rebuild. Ive also deleted the build folder and tried rebuilding that way. Im almost positive im including the module and my code correctly as ive read numerous tutorials and threads about how to do it.

To install the module i placed the .zip in my project root and let it install when it tries to build. It creates all the proper folders and places the files accordingly. Everything seems correct.

My TiApp.xml

```
<modules>
 <module platform="iphone" version="1.0">com.zooz.ti</module>
 <module platform="android" version="1.0">com.zooz.ti</module> 
</modules>
```

Comment: Nevermind this.

There was an extra step that i had skipped. I had to edit my titanium.xcodeproj file in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Adding modules to `titanium` is a bit buggy and many small details needs to be correct, here are a few:

1. The module version is the right one and written correctly in tiapp.xml
2. Make sure that also the version that is inside the module manifest file matches the version you point to.
3. If you upgrade a module version, a clean build need to be executed.
4. Minimum SDK version - checkout that the module min titanium sdk version parameter has lower value then the SDK you use.

Regarding the specific ZooZ module. There is a new version much more stable and easier steps to integrate for `iOS` and `Android`. For `iOS` use version 1.2 and Android 1.1. In the new `iOS` version you don't need the extra step of modifying `titanium` default `xcode project`.